# How to get the difference in days between 2 timestamps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I have a table named `accounts`. I am interested in retrieving those accounts whose status has not been updated since more than 10 days. I thought about this query and it seemed to work but I am not sure it's the best approach:

```
SELECT * from accounts
WHERE status = 'PENDING_PAYMENT'
AND (date_part('day', (now() - status_updated_at)) > 10);
```

One thing I don't like about this is the `now()` part. It would be ideal if `now()` was not calculated for each record and instead be a single timestamp value calculated at the beginning. Moreover, I would like this example to return `1`:

Suppose that for one record the `status_updated_at` column has this value: `2015-10-05 23:00:00`. And `now()` returns `2015-10-06 01:00:00`. Despite being only some hours of difference I want the result to be `1`.

Comment: And by `whose status has been updated since more than 10 days` you mean `whose status has` ***`not`*** `been updated since more than 10 days`, right?

Comment: Exactly, I meant `not`, will edit the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simplify your expression with the function [`age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE) (returns `interval`). But it's much more efficient to use a [sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable) expression to begin with.

This operates with the exact time difference (current time is relevant):

```
SELECT *
FROM   accounts
WHERE  status = 'PENDING_PAYMENT'
AND    status_updated_at < now() - interval '10 days';
```

To operate with whole calendar days (up to but excluding midnight, local time zone):

```
...
AND    status_updated_at < CURRENT_DATE - 10;
```

Subtracting `integer` from `date` yields `date`, which can be compared to `timestamp` directly.

You seem to be asking for the behavior of the **second variant**. The difference is *more* than 10 days.

#### How does the evaluation work?

In reply to your comment.

`CURRENT_DATE` is a special function returning the current `date` (implemented internally with `('now'::cstring)::date` in pg 9.4). There are many variants of the operator `-`. I find 43 in the system catalog `pg_operator` in my current test DB. The right one is picked for the operands' data types.

For `date - integer`, the `integer` number of days is subtracted from the `date`. Modern Postgres stores dates and timestamps as `integer` quantities internally. It's *very* cheap to transform one into the other, add/subtract days to/from a `date`, or compare them.

The result of the expression is a `date`, while `status_updated_at` is a `timestamp` column. I was assuming an implicit assignment cast at first, but that step is not even necessary, `date` and `timestamp` share a binary compatible format and can be compared directly. There is a variant of the `<` operator registered for `timestamp < date`. Column values can be tested "as is", the expression is sargable, a btree index can be used.

```
SELECT oprname, oprleft::regtype, oprright::regtype
FROM   pg_operator
WHERE  oprname = '<'
AND    oprleft = 'timestamp'::regtype;
```

Related:

- [Generate series of dates - using date type as input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21051215/939860)

With `timestamptz`, the matter of time zones would be added to the equation, which is complex but typically burns down to very simple evaluation:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

#### Volatility of `now()`

> It would be ideal if `now()` was not calculated for each record and
> instead be a single timestamp value calculated at the beginning.

Your **wish has been granted**. The `now()` family of functions (including `CURRENT_DATE` id defined `STABLE`, i.e. `now()` returns the same value within the same transaction.

- [now() default values are all showing same timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12216802/939860)
- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behavior of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28573737/939860)

Comment: Thanks a lot @erwin-brandstetter for the complete answer and extra info. Learnt a bit about _STABLE_ functions and _sargables_. The solution is clear, however I still have a doubt. In your second solution `[...] status_updated_at < CURRENT_DATE - 10` I don't understand how the comparisson and coercion works. `status_updated_at` is a timestamp. `CURRENT_DATE` is a date. First of all, when you are substracting `10` from `CURRENT_DATE`  why that `10` represents days and not other time unit. Finally, in the `<` comparisson, I am comparing a timestamp vs a date, date is coerced to a timestamp?

Comment: @flyer88: I added a detailed explanation.