# Passing value of datatype interval in parametrized query

Tags: postgresql, datatypes, parameter, postgresql-10, interval

The context is connecting to a Postgres db from a rest server.

To consider a hypothetical representative example: I would like to be able to get a list of names where the account creation date is older/newer than an arbitrary value.

In the example query below, the table structure is simple - `name` is of type `text`, and `creation_date` is of type `timestamp`. So when I do something like

```
server_pg_module:query("select name from new_table where 
current_timestamp - creation_date < '6 days'")
```

it works nicely. But what I really want to do is get that value of `6 days` from the server. So I try something like

```
server_pg_module:query("select name from new_table where
current_timestamp - timestamp < $1", ["6 days"]
```

it throws an error. I tried `'6 days'`, `"'6 days'"` and a few other concoctions, all throw errors. So to check I added a new column `interval` of type `interval` and tried a query like

```
server_pg_module:query("insert into new_table (name, interval) values ($1, '3 day')", ["fooo"]).
```

which works, but

```
server_pg_module:query("insert into new_table (name, interval) values ($1, $2)", ["fooo", "3 days"]).
```

breaks. For good measure, in addition to the concoctions like `"'3 days'"` mentioned above I also tried `$2::interval` (which I am not sure is legit), but it doesn't work.

Thus I believe it might either have something to do with expressing an interval in a param query, or something peculiar about the module I am using. Any ideas on what causes the trouble and how to do this sort of thing would be appreciated. Or may be it can be narrowed down that the problem is not with pg but with the module, then I have to address it elsewhere.

Postgres version: 10.x

The module I am using is pgo (for the Erlang programming language) https://github.com/SpaceTime-IoT/pgo. The error message I get (when I pass `"2 days"` or `"'2 days'"` as the query parameter) looks like:

```
{error,{pgsql_error,#{code => <<"08P01">>,file => <<"pqformat.c">>,
                          line => <<"575">>,
                          message => <<"insufficient data left in message">>,
                          routine => <<"pq_copymsgbytes">>,severity => <<"ERROR">>,
                          {unknown,86} => <<"ERROR">>}}}
```

And when I pass `'2 days'` as the parameter, it throws a `badarg` error.

Comment: you don't say which error that gets you.

Comment: You should include the verbatim error message and the "module" you are using. I am sure there are much better solutions.

Comment: @Jasen yes, done that now...

Comment: it seems like your postgresql syntax is correct.  it could be some bug in the Erlang library you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TLDR: Skip to chapter "Superior query" below.

You didn't disclose the module you are working with, but the problem is obviously one of **type casting**. Looks like your parameter is passed as ***typed*** value, and I assume `text` or `varchar`. There is no implicit type cast for `text` -> `interval`:

> ```
> SELECT castsource::regtype, casttarget::regtype, castcontext
> FROM   pg_cast
> WHERE  casttarget = 'interval'::regtype;
> ```
>
> ```
> castsource             | casttarget | castcontext
> :--------------------- | :--------- | :----------
> time without time zone | interval   | i          
> interval               | interval   | i
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=220833d7208da4753975c0f251dbdd34)*

If my assumptions are correct you should see an error message like:

> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval < text
> ```

I am pretty confident your undisclosed module has ways to pass a different data type or an untyped string literal. Postgres does offer this functionality.

You also state:

> I also tried `$2::interval`

This is odd, because an explicit type cast *should* also work.

#### Demo

> ```
> -- interval typed value
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < interval '6 days'; -- works
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

> ```
> --untyped string literal
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < '6 days'; -- works
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

> ```
> -- text typed value
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < text '6 days'; -- fails!
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval < text
> ```

LINE 2: ... current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < text '6 ...
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

> 

> ```
> -- text typed value, with explicit cast
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < ('6 days'::text::interval); -- works
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

The same is true for prepared statements:

> ```
> PREPARE fooplan_typed_interval(interval) AS
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < $1;
>
> EXECUTE fooplan_typed_interval('6 days');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

> ```
> PREPARE fooplan_untyped AS
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < $1;
>
> EXECUTE fooplan_untyped('6 days');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

> ```
> PREPARE fooplan_typed_text(text) AS
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < $1;
>
> EXECUTE fooplan_typed_text('6 days');  -- only this one fails!
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  operator does not exist: interval < text
> ```

LINE 3: ...ELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < $1;
^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

> 

> ```
> PREPARE fooplan_typed_text(text) AS
> SELECT current_timestamp - timestamp '2018-05-04 18:40' < $1::interval;
>
> EXECUTE fooplan_typed_text('6 days');
> ```
>
> ```
> | ?column? |
> | :------- |
> | f        |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=371152cdf1563e1a539b23230a23fff0)*

### Superior query

All this aside, neither of your queries can use an index (not "sargable").
**Use something like this instead!**

```
server_pg_module:query("select name from new_table
where creation_date > localtimestamp - interval '1 day' * $1", [6])
```

You can multiply an `interval` with `integer`.
Or if you figure out the problem with passing typed parameters:

```
server_pg_module:query("select name from new_table
where creation_date > localtimestamp - $1::interval", ['6 days'])
```

Using [`localtimestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) to point out that the "current time" depends on your current time zone setting with the type `timestamp`. Details:

- [How to get the difference in days between 2 timestamps in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/105820/how-to-get-the-difference-in-days-between-2-timestamps-in-postgresql/105821#105821)
- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Hi Erwin the "superior query" you  suggested works like a charm. Your point on "sargability" is critical though, never knew that word. Many thanks for the detailed answer, especially for the sargable bit. My query could have ruined performance down the line.

Comment: The server module in question is https://github.com/SpaceTime-IoT/pgo for Erlang. Your diagnosis is correct, it has to do with typecasting, but there might be more to it than that. In Erlang, writing something within single quotes is a way of expressing an "atom", a built in datatype. So when one gives '2 days', the module handling the protocol might be getting confused. I updated the question with the error message it throws.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a workaround to achieve the same objective.

The approach leverages the fact that the difference of two dates is an integer; it is straightforward to cast a timestamp into a date, and integer values can be used in parametrized queries from the server to the db.

```
server_pg_module:query("select name from new_table where 
current_timestamp::date - timestamp::date < $1", [6])
```